# add data from edittext to listview in android

Tags: android

I have an add button, a textbox called edittext, and a listview.  When I click the add button data currently in edittext should move to list view.  How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- set **ArrayAdapter<String>** for your
  ListView
- use **insert** method of
  ArrayAdapter for move string from
  EditText to ListView
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

"edittext should move to list view".. do you mean focus to be moved to listview OR Editext must disappear and listview must appear?

To handle focus you could use setFocusable() http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#HandlingFocus

For second option, you could hide widgets in event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

@GSree it is very clear that user569553 wants that when he/she clicks on add button tha data of edittext feild should move to list.

so simply get data using getText() method and the go through this link.

best explanation i have ever found about implementation of getView() and listview.

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an in-build list adapter such as ArrayAdapter or SimpleAdapter, then all you need to is add the data from EditText.getText() to your data collection, create a NEW list adapter, then when you call setListAdapter() the listview will be refreshed with your new item added.